# Parse.com for website and mobile?

Tags: parse-platform

I all I want to find out is a dilemma. Can I use Parse for my web online application (Computers) and in parallel to that in Mobile Applications like iOS and Android?

Comment: Normally if you use the same record, you can configure it on all the platforms available with Parse.

Comment: yes (of course) you can, that would be terrible otherwise